# scale_x_continuous adjusting data

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, histogram

I have a set of data I'm running through a histogram on a shiny application. The range of values on the x axis is from 0-700 and the y axis is the proportionate frequency of each increment (binwidth =5). I added on the `scale_x_continuous` with a `sliderInput` in order to allow the x axis to adjust. For instance, I just want to see the proportionate frequency of the x values between 500 and 600. When I added this in, the resulting data shows the proportion of the data just within that one interval. For instance, if I only have 1 x value in the 500-600 range, the y axis will show 1 (that 1 value in the 500-600 range constitutes 100% of the values in the 500-600 range). However, I would like this to still use the same proportions as if the full range of x variables is displayed (i.e., the same frequency as when the x range is 0-700).

```
 output$hist <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(universe, aes(Price)) + 
    geom_histogram(data = other, binwidth = 5, fill = "red", alpha = 0.2, aes(y=..count../sum(..count..))) + 
    geom_histogram(data = barcelona, binwidth = 5, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2,aes(y=..count../sum(..count..))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(input$range[1], input$range[2]))
})
```

The above code is how I'm generating the histogram. The `input$range` is pulling from the `sliderInput` I have in the `ui.R`. Do you know how to make the selection for `scale_x_continuous` not impact the denominator of (`y=..count../sum(..count..))`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coord_cartesian(xlim=...)` instead of `scale_x_continuous()`.

Setting limits on the coordinate system will zoom the plot (like you're looking at it with a magnifying glass), and will not change the underlying data like setting limits on a scale will.